# I'm just not getting the method

Tags: logic

[image]

In the first ∆ , it's 5 + 6 + 4 = 15 which is equal to the 15 inside.
But in the 3rd ∆ it's not!!

There's no way visible through which I can get the answer.
( Question no. 26 )

Comment: Add context. Is this about triangles in some way? What is the book? Otherwise Kaind's answer below is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$2 \times \frac{5 \times 6}{4} = 15$

Comment: I never thought of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Such questions are not proper maths and are actually ridiculous - and here's why:

Consider any function from $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. According to the question, it is given that $f(5,6,4) = 15$ and $f(4,8,8) = 8$. Using this, you have to find the value of $f(6,7,12)$?

There are uncountably infinite functions which could satisfy the constraints of the problem. Even if you restrict the range and domain of $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, you still get countably infinite possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @Kaind's answer. Let me give an example to make it a bit clear (or to make it lot confused).

Let's say your pattern is $$\dfrac{\text{left most number} \times \text{right most number}}{\text{position of the triangle}+1}.$$ Then you will get $14$ as the answer, which will be different from the answer you get according to @Jens.